# Change MAX_BODY_LENGTH of message in telapi-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms

I'm using [telapi-ruby](https://github.com/TelAPI/telapi-ruby) to send SMS, as the following:

```
def self.send_demo_sms(phone, message)
    Telapi::Message.create(phone, FROM_NUM, ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(message))
end
```

I got this error `Body must be between 0 and 160 characters`, I check the [message class](https://github.com/TelAPI/telapi-ruby/blob/master/lib/telapi/message.rb).

Do I need to override this constant to avoid this error, so How I can do that ? Or

What's the solution to send message has 230 character as my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding in the gem would be pointless if the API has a character limit. Why don't you make two requests?